# Why does this compile and is there any compiler switch that can make the compiler report it as an error or warning?

Tags: c++, qt, g++

I found this example when I ran PCLint on the source code of the project I am working on. Here is the code snippet:

```
QString foo()
{
    return false;
}
```

I compiled the code and verified that it returns an empty string. The real example is a large method in a large class, and somewhere in some remote if branch, there was this isolated

```
return false;
```

Ok, it is bad coding, shame on the developer (by using SVN / blame I could even find out who did this :-)) but, seriously, why doesn't the compiler complain?

My theory is that the compiler translates

```
return false;
```

to

```
return QString(((const char *) false));
```

However, I do not see all the elementary steps performed by the compiler to infer this. It first tries all the constructors of QString, and finds

```
QString(const * char);
```

but then? How does it determine that it can go from bool to const char *. Or does it automatically cast a bool to any pointer type any time you use a bool where a pointer is expected?

The second part of the question. Since all these implicit type conversions are quite dangerous (why would a developer write 'return false;' if they meant "return an empty string"?), is there a way (e.g. a compiler switch) so that such situations are at least reported as a warning? I tried -Wall in g++ and it didn't print any warning.

**EDIT**

Thanks for the hints. false seems to have a special treatment. If I do

```
return true;
```

I get:

```
error: conversion from ‘bool’ to non-scalar type ‘QString’ requested
```

I am using g++ 4.4.3 on Ubuntu. As pointed out in different comments, other compilers report the problem.

Comment: clang warns about it, had a case of this a while back.

Comment: GCC (4.5 at least) **does** warn about it.

Comment: Insert plug for `explicit` constructors here.

Comment: Ok, I am using GCC 4.4.3, that might explain it. Thanks.

Comment: "Insert plug for explicit constructors here": what is this? Is there a way to force use of explicit constructors?

Comment: By declaring the constructor explicit. ;)

Comment: Well, I thought it was clear from the context that QString is a library class, and that therefore I cannot change it :-) For a moment I thought there was some compiler switch to force all constructors to be explicit.

Comment: You could make a wrapper class around QString and declare its constructor as explicit instead. And then prepare the rubber hose for anyone in your organization who dares violate the "Thou shall not use QString" commandment.

Comment: `std::string` has the exact same problem. Are you going to deprecate that as well?... I suppose they don't want to emphasize how the string literal and string class are entirely distinct by not allowing implicit conversion.

Comment: And deriving a class from QString is not really a recommendation, as QString does not have a virtual destructor.

Comment: Since [GCC 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html), a new (enabled by default) flag called `-Wconversion-null` outputs a warning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`false` equates to zero. Zero is a special case that represents the NULL pointer, and will be cast to any pointer type without warning.

I'm quite surprised that the compiler allowed this as a one-step conversion, and didn't consider it a two-step conversion from `boolean` to `int`, then `int` to `char*` - two-step conversions aren't done implicitly.

Comment: But false has type bool and 0 has type int. Is the cast performed automatically?

Comment: GCC warns about it: `warning: converting ‘false’ to pointer type for argument 1 of ‘QString::QString(const char*)’`

Comment: Strange, I do not get any warnings. Using g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3. I have -Wall on the command line.

Comment: I was quite surprised too, that's why I wanted to report this and ask for explanations. By the way, the original example was compiled on Visual Studio 8.

Comment: @Giorgio, are you sure it was the `const char*` constructor that was invoked? There's a deleted answer suggesting it was the `QChar` constructor, and that would be a one-step conversion that could be done implicitly - I'm not sure why the owner deleted it, it seems very plausible to me.

Comment: Is there a way to check which constructor was used? What should the resulting string be in either case?

Comment: `bool` is an integral type, `false` converts to 0 and is constant, and you can convert a constant integral expression evaluating to 0 for the null pointer.  (This won't work with `true`; `true` converts to 1 and there is no special pointer meaning for it.)

Comment: Since Mark B. did it for explicit constructors, I'll shamelessly throw out a plug for `nullptr` at this point.  Thanks David for making me think of it!

Comment: @MichaelPrice: I guess this should be a separate question, but how would `nullptr` fix anything? Are they going to remove 0 / NULL?

Comment: @UncleBens, it will solve the opposite problem where a NULL constant is interpreted as zero. I don't think it helps this problem at all.

Comment: @UncleBens: a nullptr_t (the type of the nullptr reserved keyword) freely (implicitly) converts to any pointer type (and to bool I think).  It cannot convert to a numeric type unless you do some casting.  Essentially, going from 0 -> a null pointer is special (as David Thornley pointed out), and it is only special because of the historical usage of NULL as a null pointer "literal". Thus, if nullptr had existed in the original C, we likely wouldn't be having this conversation.

Comment: Since [GCC 4.5](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html), a new (enabled by default) flag called `-Wconversion-null` outputs a warning.